# How add divider to material alert dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

i have the following code

```
    val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())

    with(builder) {
        setSingleChoiceItems(cities, checkedItemId) { dialog, cityId ->
        ...
```

i need to do like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnIED.png)

but i have this
how to add separators
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdHd0.png)

Comment: You can use a customView instead by using setView() method as said in docs but in that case you will have to manage the entire UI / List checks and other business logic. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder#setView(int)